# Is there an OS X app to route keyboard via bluetooth?

Tags: macos, iphone, keyboard, bluetooth

I want an app on my desktop that lets me route my keyboard to my iPhone via bluetooth.

The main goal is to type with the keyboard when I get a text. I don't mind having to click a button on an app.  It would be nice if I can share it via bluetooth? So i can register it as a keyboard on my iPhone. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

## [Type2Phone](http://www.houdah.com/type2Phone/)

This app does pretty much exactly what you're looking for. It turns your Mac into a Bluetooth keyboard that you can pair your iOS device to. When you type into the app, that text gets sent to the device as if you were using a directly connected keyboard.

It's [available on the Mac App Store for $4.99](https://itunes.apple.com/app/tembo/id472717129?mt=12).

Answer (score 0):

For a cheaper approach, if you are okay with jailbreaking - I put Veency (http://www.tuaw.com/2008/09/18/veency-vnc-server-for-iphone/) on the iphone and then I remote desktop in when I want to type - this has the advantage that you can see what you are doing on the big screen, you also get mouse access, and it's very handy if you ever want to demo anything.